# Can I get a bigger basket?

Tags: atelier-meruru-apprentice-of-arland

In *Atelier Totori* I missed getting the bigger basket until I was about 90% of the way through the game, even though you can trigger the event for it fairly early. It was... sad.

I have just started *Atelier Meruru* and this time I want to get any such event as early as possible. Can I get a bigger basket? In the least-plot-spoilery way, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trigger the event by **buying lots of stuff from Hanna**, though I'm not sure how much. (I got it at the same time I got *Society Class C*, which is a development goal achieved by spending money - so it might be the same requirement.)

She gives you an alchemy recipe for a **Handmade Basket**, which requires

> Hay x3, (Cloth) x2, (Threads) x2.

It increases your basket space from 60 to 80; if you synth it at a higher quality it can carry up to 100.

To equip the new basket, put it in your basket, then select it and choose "Equip" from the menu.